# MS Access SQL: Left Join for Selection List with Checkboxes

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to follow the example provided here(https://www.databasedevelopment.co.uk/examples.htm) to get an MS Access subform with checkboxes for selection.

**tbl_Employee_Selected**

| ID | EmployeeID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | John Smith |
| 2 | 1235 | Jane Smith |

**tbl_Simple_selected**

| selectedID | EmployeeID | Selected |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | Yes/No |
| 2 |  | Yes/No |

```
SELECT tbl_Employee_Selected.ID, tbl_Employee_Selected.EmployeeID, tbl_Employee_Selected.FirstName, tbl_Employee_Selected.LastName, tbl_Simple_selected.Selected
FROM tbl_Employee_Selected 
LEFT JOIN tbl_Simple_selected ON tbl_Employee_Selected.ID = tbl_Simple_selected.EmployeeID;
```

The issue is that with the above SQL I get the "SelectedID" in the created table instead of the actual employee ID. If I try any other join criteria, I can't update the record set because I'm not using Primary keys.

Comment: I am reviewing the example db. I don't see those tables nor query. Exactly what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I renamed from their example. I believe the original was “Categories” and “SimpleSelect”.

Answer (score 2):

Do you care, or need a temp table?

You can select rows from a "grid" (continuous form) without having a check box column.

So, the form code we build a "collection" that keeps track of the selected rows.

The code looks like this:

```
  Option Compare Database
  Option Explicit
  
  Public CheckItems As New Collection
  
  Public Function MySel(vID As Variant) As Boolean
  
     If IsNull(vID) Then
        MySel = False
        Exit Function
     End If
     ' check if id exists in colleciton.
     On Error Resume Next
     Dim mydummy As Variant
     mydummy = CheckItems(CStr(vID))
     If Err.Number = 0 Then
        ' found it, return true!!
        MySel = True
        Exit Function
     End If
     
     MySel = False
  
  End Function
  
  
  Private Sub cmdCheck_Click()
  
     ' check in our list
     If MySel(Me!ID) Then
        ' already in list - remove
        CheckItems.Remove CStr(Me!ID)
     Else
        ' not in the list - add it
        CheckItems.Add Me!ID.Value, CStr(Me!ID)
     End If
     
     Me.ckSel.Requery
  
  End Sub
```

So, the "trick" here is we bind the check box to the MySel function. Because the check box is now bound to that function, then we can NOT click on that check box.

So, the check box is now bound like this:

[image]

so, the SelChk function is passed the PK of the given row.

Now, to check/un-check, we drop a button (invisible) on TOP of the check box.

like this:

[image]

Don't forget to bring to front this button - we MAKE SURE it is on top of the check box.

hence this:

[image]

So, put all above together, and we have this:

[image]

Of course we now want a final button that takes the selection, and we can run a report, or even process the records. The code can be this:

```
Dim strWhere      As String
Dim v             As Variant

For Each v In CheckItems
  If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere = strWhere & ","
  strWhere = strWhere & v
Next
```

' open a report based on selection

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptHotelsInvoice", acViewPreview, , "ID IN (" & strWhere & ")"
```

Or, we could process the records in code, say like this:

```
  Dim strWhere      As String
  Dim v             As Variant
  
  For Each v In CheckItems
     If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere = strWhere & ","
     strWhere = strWhere & v
  Next
  
  Dim strSQL As String
  
  strSQL = "SELECT * from tblHotels where ID IN (" & strWhere & ")"
  Debug.Print strSQL
  
  Dim rst     As DAO.Recordset
  Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

  Do While rst.EOF = False
  
      ' process reocrds
      rst.Edit
      rst("FirstName") = rst("FirstName") & "z"
      
      rst.Edit
      rst("FirstName") = rst("FirstName") & "z"
      
      rst.Update
      rst.MoveNext
  Loop
  rst.Close
```

Now, we assumed a "ID" for PK, but if your pk id is different, then change this:

```
MySql([ID])  to whatever your PK row ID is. the rest of the code should work as is.
```

And the final bit of code above that creates the WHERE clause, again would be changed.

so, all in all?

You really don't need a temp table, and using the above custom collection and a function to drive the check box means you don't need a extra table.

The beauty of above?

You can use this against say a linked Excel sheet, SharePoint tables, SQL server tables - it doesn't matter, since we are not messing or dealing with an extra table.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! Is there a way to prevent all of the other selection boxes in the underlying form from "flashing" when you select one? When I click the transparent button, all of the other boxes display a filled in black box (regardless of their status) for a second before updating to their last selected/un-selected status.

Comment: don't have a fix for that, and I note this is a issue. The less records, the less conditional formatting, and the cleaner the data source is the better this works, but it sill will flicker. Don't have any rows say with a dlookup(), and try to keep the sql and the row formats "limited" with conditional formatting etc. The cleaner the form, the less the flicker - but you do have to live with it. It not too bad -but never the less is a legitimate annoy here. I have a newer version in which I don't use a check box, but only ONE text box (with a X that appears - it somewhat better, not by much)

Answer (score 0):

How about joining on `EmployeeID`:

```sql
SELECT 
    tbl_Employee_Selected.ID, 
    tbl_Employee_Selected.EmployeeID, 
    tbl_Employee_Selected.FirstName, 
    tbl_Employee_Selected.LastName, 
    tbl_Simple_selected.Selected
FROM 
    tbl_Employee_Selected 
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl_Simple_selected 
    ON tbl_Employee_Selected.EmployeeID = tbl_Simple_selected.EmployeeID;
```

Comment: I cant because then the recordset is not updateable. I believe this is because EmployeeID is not the Primary Key.

Comment: @user2059972 For update query you need domain aggregation functions like DLOOKUP(), DSUM(), DMIN(), DMAX() etc.

Comment: But the original query works if the join is on the primary key without using those keywords. The issue is I want the query to update but report back a different field than the primary key one.